# Rails: Implement Search/Filter like Amazon.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement a search feature on a model that is based on several attributes. I'd like to allow the user to be able to specify which attributes to filter on. It would be very similar to any e-commerce site such as Amazon.com

For example, the user can filter on based on
- author
- rating
- category

any advise would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is often called 'faceted' search. Try:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2
- https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented search before and I have great luck with this

http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised

This have to advantage of saving the searches, be in it's own model to not blot the other model, and easily implemented without any gems.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend using [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to handle your faceting for you, so consider using [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) as your Ruby/Rails abstraction over Solr.

As you can see from the documentation, you can define field facets in this manner:

```
# Posts that match 'pizza' returning counts for each :author_id
search = Post.search do
  fulltext "pizza"
  facet :author_id
end

search.facet(:author_id).rows.each do |facet|
  puts "Author #{facet.value} has #{facet.count} pizza posts!"
end
```

Sunspot's integration with Rails also makes maintaining the Solr index a lot easier by automatically indexing objects in the `save` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, but I didn't want to use an external service like Solr, or ElasticSearch so I built this gem: https://github.com/fortytools/forty_facets

Comment: How much is performance affected without Solr or ElasticSearch? When do you see scaling issues?

Comment: It's hard to come up with general metrics since the actual speed depends on your schema and your data.
The filtering is done via pretty straight forward joins and where(...) queries.
So everything you do in your normal controller methods to speed up queries applies here to
For each Facet there happens one 'GROUP-BY' query. These can vary greatly in cost depending on number of facets and facet values.
I don't consider myself a DB expert, but with just slapping indices on all relevant columns I've had no issues filtering on datasets with up to 100K rows of 'base' entities and 4-5 facets.